# How to reproduce the Unsub histogram in Altair?

Tags: python, altair, vega-lite

Unsub's histogram display stacks each journal title on top of each other as an individual box, then ranks by cost per use on the x-axis.

https://i.ibb.co/2FvXhFp/unsub.jpg (can't post images due to my new account)

I want to reproduce this in Altair, I can't figure out how to "break up" the histogram's bars.

https://i.ibb.co/jzX4N2r/altair.jpg

```
    hist = alt.Chart(df[filt_to_100]).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X('cpu:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=100)),
    y='count()'
    ).interactive()
hist
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the y=count() function, but I can't find a way to make it show individual points.  I also tried switching it to a mark_circle(), but that doesn't look right either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replicate it to an extent via the `detail` parameter. However, the white lines are not added for each observations, I'm not sure if it is because they are aligning to play nicely with what is on the axis (I tried setting `nice=False` but to no avail), maybe someone more knowledgeable can fill in.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source.reset_index(), height=200).mark_bar().encode(
    alt.X("Horsepower", bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=50)),
    alt.Y('count()', axis=alt.Axis(grid=False)),
    alt.Detail('index')
).configure_view(strokeWidth=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to follow along and reproduce what you have.  It must be the reset_index() that's making the magic happen.  To make sure I understand what you did, you've reset the index back to 0-n, and then using the alt.Detail to count them?  I might not totally understand the alt.Detail('index') line...

Comment: @eschares The detail channel can be used to specify additional summary and group-by fields, without mapping the field(s) to any visual properties like color. I believe that using a column that has one unique values per observation,  such as the index, means that we will create one bar per observation / group stacked on top of each other and the white line are the outlines of those bars (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with similar result would be to reformat your dataframe to have a column that runs from 0 to the max count for each bin and then plot it using `mark_rect`:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

# Add index from zero to max count (bin height) for each group
source2 = source.groupby('Horsepower', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True)).reset_index()

alt.Chart(source2, height=200, width=800).mark_rect(size=8, strokeWidth=1, stroke='white').encode(
    alt.X('Horsepower:O'),
    alt.Y('level_1:O', title='Count', scale=alt.Scale(reverse=True)),
)
```

You could use `pd.cut` to split horsepower into intervals if you wanted it to be more similar to the histogram x-axis, but you can't use the interval datatype directly in Altair so you would need to assign a number to each bin.

[image]