# Creating custom bar chart in Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I am a newbie to `Vega-Lite` and I am trying to replicate a chart similar to this

[image: Desired Chart]

Following is my code and it does not generate what I need.

```
{
   "$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
   "width":800,
   "height":600,
   "autosize":{
      "type":"fit",
      "contains":"padding"
   },
   "data":{
      "url":"data/cars.json"
   },
   "mark":{
      "type":"rect",
      "tooltip":true,
      "strokeWidth":0.1,
      "stroke":"white"
   },
   "encoding":{
      "x":{
         "field":"Horsepower",
         "type":"quantitative",
         "bin":{
            "maxbins":100
         },
         "axis":{
            "labelAngle":0
         }
      },
      "y":{
         "aggregate":"count",
         "field":"Horsepower",
         "type":"quantitative"
      }
   }
}
```

Here is what it does

[image: SourceCode]

What do I need to do to be able to get my desired output? There is a question here already asked on the topic [How to reproduce the Unsub histogram in Altair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257246/how-to-reproduce-the-unsub-histogram-in-altair) but it was done in `python` `altair`, which I am not trying to do. I want to generate that using solely `Vega-Lite`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [bin transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bin.html#transform) followed by a [window transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html) to generate the fields required to create this kind of chart. For example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygK4CcA29zQgegMYWQGcA6AK0IHsA7EAXwBoQpkIrCAzC5AW3gG1QAIwCWNBCG4QAHiLbwArAAYGIdsICmqMBgASXQuoAOFAO7rkIRhEK79R0+br1QJ0WFP9QFQxlwVEVFCWINYYbupSdAC6jADmyP6GggCe-CB6RPZmFlG0MRIEANbwoFDJhuoYyOq4QYxQFBSoUMI+cMyI6oyEzBSF6gDqwmBQABbwisQAzN29-Rgmo8JQlSrqVH5gorElIJHiapracOl2xtnBZRUYAI6IrC0wLQBulYyyGLJU6toqUgBMu0OWlsmXO5gA+utfoxUgcNCCTuFIvVypUTlwtlQIOhuvhUOjQNVXpl4B11CpHgTfP5AnQVK4RuM4AAWRSKRijdTCWKjIJwKbs2hAA)):

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "transform": [
    {"bin": {"maxbins": 50}, "field": "Horsepower", "as": "Horsepower"},
    {"window": [{"op": "count", "as": "index"}], "groupby": ["Horsepower"]}
  ],
  "mark": {
    "type": "rect",
    "tooltip": true,
    "strokeWidth": 0.3,
    "stroke": "white"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative", "bin": "binned"},
    "x2": {"field": "Horsepower_end"},
    "y": {
      "field": "index",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "scale": {"reverse": true},
      "title": "count"
    }
  },
  "width": 400,
  "height": 300
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a very nice solution. Please let me study this and get back to you with some following question. Thanks a lot.